# Why does my alpha value not update in cv2.addWeighted?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am attempting to use a grid of rectangles over my live webcam video with dynamically changing transparencies across the screen. The test I am doing here does not hold the dynamic aspect, but the rectangles should be different transparencies according to their normalized value in the rng array of values. All of the rectangles in the grid are resulting as the same transparency.

```
#===========================================================================================================================
# Import Necessary Libraries

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import math
import itertools
  
#===========================================================================================================================
# Define a Video Capture

vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

#===========================================================================================================================
# Initialize

height = int(input('Define Number of Rows: '))
width = int(input('Define Number of Columns: '))
hxw = height * width

#===========================================================================================================================
# Create a Random Number Array

randnums= np.random.randint(1,30000,(hxw))
normran = (randnums - randnums.min())/((randnums.max() - randnums.min()))
        
print(normran)

#===========================================================================================================================
# Create a Color Map

def colorgrid(img, normran):
    
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    
    dy = h / height
    dx = w / width

    g = np.linspace(0, w-dx, width)
    b = np.linspace(g[1], w, width)
    t = np.linspace(0, h-dy, height)
    k = np.linspace(t[1], h, height)
    
    overlay = img.copy()
    
    thickness = 2
    color3 = (0, 0, 0)
            
    color2 = (0, 0, 255)
    thickness1 = -1
    
    i = -1
    
    for spy, spay in itertools.product(t, k):
        for spx, spax in itertools.product(g, b):
            
            i = i + 1
            alpha = normran[i]
            
            spx = int(round(spx))
            spax = int(round(spax))
            spy = int(round(spy))
            spay = int(round(spay))
                
            startx = (spx, spy)
            stopx = (spax, spay)
            
            print(alpha)
            print(i)
            
            cv.rectangle(overlay, startx, stopx, color2, thickness1)
            imgnew = cv.addWeighted(overlay, normran[i], img, 1, 0)
            cv.rectangle(img, startx, stopx, color3, thickness)
            
            if (i) == (hxw-1):
                i = -1
                break

    return imgnew

#===========================================================================================================================
# Use the Camera

while(True):
    
    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
      
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame

    ret, frame = vid.read()
    
    frame = cv.flip(frame,1)

    clr = colorgrid(frame, normran)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('Test', clr)
      
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to use a for loop that increments for the number of grid spaces defined and will end when the number of spaces are up. This is successful, but it seems as the image only results in the alpha value associated with normran[end]. The output of the input of 3 rows and 3 columns is:

```
0.90409176345848
0
0.07855800279531544
1
0.4564557328064003
2
0.9938310280013495
3
0.0
4
0.16005590630873778
5
1.0
6
0.9541182707600366
7
0.1760566774302376
8
0.90409176345848
0
0.07855800279531544
1
0.4564557328064003
2
0.9938310280013495
3
0.0
4
0.16005590630873778
5
1.0
6
0.9541182707600366
7
0.1760566774302376
8

^^ this repeats infinitely
```

[An image of the live webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bYA.png)

Comment: In every iteration I think you compute adfWeighted on the whole image and a copy of the whole image. Is right thst you instead want to perform this on subimages sized like your rectangles?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want